# Can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str error on verifying key of signing key

Tags: python, ecdsa

I am trying to follow [this excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX-XokHf_nI) that unfortunately has the script written for python 2. I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import codecs
import ecdsa

key = "bbe5b8853f51285a62f1276b72a162365f0a51c607e38cecb9bcffdf7284b2bc"

keyhex = codecs.decode(key, 'hex')

sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(keyhex, curve = ecdsa.SECP256k1)

vk = sk.get_verifying_key().to_string()

pk = '\x04' + vk
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../sh.key-info", line 30, in <module>
    pk = '\x04' + vk
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

I thought `to_string()` would convert the verifying key to string, but apparently not? How can I make this code work properly in 3.x?

Comment: When I get these similar errors, I try checking each type of variable before the line causing the error, i.e. inspect `type(sk)`, `type(vk)`, to eventually fix the `TypeError`

Comment: The project's Github page [tells us](https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa#usage): `Note: while the methods are called to_string() the type they return is actually bytes, the "string" part is leftover from Python 2.`

Comment: If the problem is with converting between `bytes` and `string`, then you should first make sure you understand what each of those types means in Python; then you should figure out which result you actually want. The age of the project hints that there might be some bytes/str issues - it is, per the PyPI page, leaning on `six` to function properly on 3.x.

Comment: Please do not to call things "syntax errors" when the error message is very clearly telling you `TypeError:`.

Comment: `to_string()` obviously is misleading.  The authors if they had Karl's sense would rename it appropriately.  Do you agree Karl?

Comment: I do agree; it should be renamed.

Comment: To be fair, the differences between Python 2 & 3 regarding strings vs bytes can be hard for even veteran Python 2 coders to get used to. And a library that has a `.to_string` method that actually returns a `bytes` is downright confusing. OTOH, doing a search for that 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str' error message *should* have led to helpful existing answers.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411959).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the [ecdsa PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/ecdsa/):

> Note: while the methods are called `to_string()` the type they return is actually `bytes`, the "string" part is leftover from Python 2.

To fix your error, I would recommend adding a bytes object rather than converting everything to strings.

```
pk = b'\x04' + vk
```